# How to call a java class from a callback function in a dll?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am writing a software test automation tool and I have a Journal Record Proc in a DLL.
Now when the Proc gets called by Windows I want to call a method in a Java class from it. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through JNI directly. See the [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

See this part of the documentation for [how to access fields and methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17074) from the Java class. If you're calling the DLL from Java, you can pass a jobject into the method.

An alternative that makes this much simpler is the commercial product CodeMesh JunC++ion.